# How To Convert Firebase object into an Array

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, nuxt.js

I am working with Firebase Firestore using Nuxt js and I want to retrieve data from my database. I am using firebase with NuxtFirebase, the official plugin for firebase.  Though I get a list of objects instead of an array, how do I convert it into an array?

```
//post.js





const actions = {

// The Post list API 


async postList({commit}){

    try{
      
      
      const req = await this.$fire.firestore.collection('Post').get()
  
      req.forEach((doc) => {
          // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots

          const posts = doc.data()
          

          console.log(posts)

         commit("SET_POST", posts)
          
        });
        
       
    
      
      }
      catch(e){
      
      console.log(e)
      }
      
      },
  





};


export default {

state,
getters,
mutations,
actions,
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do the trick:

```
const querySnapshot = await this.$fire.firestore.collection('Post').get()
const arrayOfDocs = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());
```

The [`docs`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#docs) property of a `QuerySnapshot` returns an array of all the documents in the `QuerySnapshot`.

Comment: Glad I could help you @UdemezueJohn! You may accept and upvote the answer in such a way other SO users with the same problem see that this answer solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks , I will do that, also I need a little bit of help, I want to get some data out of the Query such as doc.id and many more, I tried formating the code this way.



```
const arrayOfDocs = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => 
{
'id':doc.id,
'content':doc.content
});

```

Comment: You should use `doc.data()`. `content` is not a property of a `DocumentSnapshot`.

Comment: I need to Query the ID and some specific details in the Array

Comment: I understand that content is a field of the document. If this assumption is true then do as follows: `const arrayOfDocs = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => { 'id':doc.id, 'content':doc.get('content') });` (see the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.documentsnapshot#documentsnapshotget) for the `get()` method). Also, do not forget to accept the answer if it solved your question.

Comment: Thanks but I get an error when I try to log in to my console

Here is my code.

```
 const arrayOfDocs= querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => {

  'id':doc.id,
 });


SyntaxError: C:\Users\JS\Desktop\Front-End\newsly-nuxt\store\modules\post.js: Missing semicolon.

```